# Windows classic start menu on Kubuntu

Tags: linux, menu

I am looking for a program that can replace/modify the default Kubuntu menu ([Kickoff Application Launcher](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff)) so that the menu is organized like the Windows classic start menu (Windows 2000). I don't care about the look of the menu but rather its organization.

I want:

- all programs to be in the same folder
- a multi-column list: I don't want to have to scroll anything
- the solution to work with Kubuntu 14.04 or 14.10 (KDE)

The following gives an example (using [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate):

[image: Screenshot of Classic Shell]

If possible, as in the example above:

- Access to the last launched programs in 2 clicks: one click on "start", one click on the program. E.g. "TexMaker" at the top left in the screenshot.
- Ability to set some programs to be accessible in in 2 clicks: one click on "start", one click on the program. E.g. "VNC Addess Book" or "SmartNav" in the screenshot.

Also, it would be great if it could be set to have no menu delay, as we can do in Classic Shell:

[image: Screenshof Classic Shell’s settings]

Comment: The **Application Launcher Menu** widget looks very much like the Windows classic start menu with multi-columns, except that the programs are sorted into categories. You could get them under one folder if you add everything to Favorites, but even within categories, it still takes two clicks to get to any program. You can add this menu using **Add Widgets** or by right-clicking on the K-Launcher icon and selecting **Switch to Classic Menu Style**

Comment: You say that all programs should be in the same folder, but you show a list with many subfolder. Did you mean that there should be one folder per package (which is what traditional versions of Windows do)?

Comment: @Gilles All programs should be in the same folder: on Windows most applications have indeed their own folders, which I find inefficient.

Comment: @Timmy Thanks that's indeed a great option. Any idea 1. How to  easily put all programs in the favorites folder? 2. [How to remove the menu delay?](http://askubuntu.com/q/545272/44876) 3. [How to display more than 10 recently used applications?](http://askubuntu.com/q/545259/44876) 4.  Is Kickoff multi-column though (i.e. if there are too many programs to be displayed in 1 column, does Kickoff display 2 columns or do we need to scroll?)?

Comment: Yes for (4), I have enough Utilities for 2 colums. [Here's a recording](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21905617/2014-11-04%2000h35_03.mp4). I would also like to see answers for the other 3 questions

Comment: @Timmy Btw I asked the last question here: [Gathering all programs in one submenu in Kickoff Application Launcher](http://askubuntu.com/q/545372/44876)

Comment: Note that [Xubuntu has a menu for **All** programs](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Screen-Shot-2013-10-29-at-20.24.46.png). Maybe there is a way to copy that configuration into Kick-off